# Filtering and formatting json data python

Tags: python, json, http

I'm trying to filter a data that is in json format but after it did the json.dumps it's still not in dict format and when I try to filter it, doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
import json
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

user = ''

def data_json():
    url = ''+user
    r = http.request(
        'GET', 
        url,
    )
    data = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
    data2 = json.dumps(dados, indent=4, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':'))

    print (data2)
```

This is the output that it returns:

```
{
    "result":"Data: {\"prescription":\"Nimesulida \",\"data\":\"14/10\"}"
}
```

And I would like to filter just the 'data' result from this output, I've tried this two ways:

```
print(data2[1]['data']) 
print(data2['result']['data'])
```

but it returns this error message: string indices must be integers. Does anyone know how can I filter this data?

Comment: The value of result is a string

Comment: No need to do `data = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))` , simply do `data = r.json()`.  from requests`.json()` returns the json format already , nothing to do decode

Comment: data = r.json() does not work, it raises this error: AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'json'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a bit of a mess.  While the JSON is valid, it is oddly formed.  Below I've reverse-engineered the original `data` value since it wasn't provided directly:

```py
import json
import ast

data2 = r'''{
    "result":"Data: {\"prescription\":\"Nimesulida \",\"data\":\"14/10\"}"
}'''
print(data2)  # Matches your claim,^-except there was a missing backslash here

data = json.loads(data2)  # Get original data back
print(data)

result = data['result']   # access result, value is a *string*

d = ast.literal_eval(result[6:]) # slice off 'Data: ' and convert to dict
print(d['data'])
```

Output:

```
14/10
```

Comment: it worked! I didn't knew about this ast lib, it is great